# How to change Route Model Binding finding data from id to slug

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, route-model-binding

I have a route like the following.

```
Route::get('/articles/{articleSlug}' , 
    [App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'single']);
```

And the method of `single()` at `ArticleController` class goes here:

```
public function single($slug)
{
    $article = Article::where('slug',$slug)->first();
    $article->increment('viewCount');

    return view('home.article',compact('article'));
}
```

Now I wish to use Route Model Binding for finding this data from the `articles` table based on the column `slug`. But as I know, Route Model Binding finds data based on the id. So how to change Route Model Binding finding data from `id` to `slug` ONLY for `ArticleController.php` (meaning that the other Controller classes can work with id as route model binding)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you want to use other model field as the biding attribute instead of `id` you can define a `getRouteKeyName` which return the name of the field which must be use

```
class Article extends Model {
    // other methods goes here
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

Or you can pass the field name directly when you define the route like this

```
Route::get('/articles/{article:slug}' , [App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'single']);
```

With this code inside of your controller you must ensure that the name provide as parameter in the route definition match the name of the `controller` argument

```
public function single(Article $article)
{
    $article->increment('viewCount');

    return view('home.article',compact('article'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your route to this:

```
Route::get('/articles/{article:slug}' , [App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'single']);
```

and then inject the Article model to your controller function and let laravel do the rest for you:

```
public function single(Article $article)
    {
        $article->increment('viewCount');
        return view('home.article',compact('article'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is already set up, all you need to do is change your variable name to $slug in the route, and I believe that should be enough:

```
Route::get('/articles/{slug}' , [App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'single']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can customize route model bindings directly in the route definition:

1. past given code in  app/model/Article.php:

   public function getRouteKeyName()
   {
   return 'slug';
   }

2.when you use slug  change route to

```
 Route::get('/articles/{article:slug}' , [App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'single']);
```

3. to use id sample change slug to id

   Route::get('/articles/{article:id}' , [App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'single']);

Answer (score 0):

you can add bind method to your model boot() like this

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::bind('article', function ($value) {
        return Article::where('slug', $value)->firstOrFail();
    });
 
}
```

to learn more about it read this section in the Laravel docs
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic